# Spring-data-elasticsearch custom date format error

Tags: java, spring, date, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I'm using spring-data-elasticsearch 4.0.1 and elastic cluster 7.6, when I define an attribute with a custom pattern with "yyyy-MM-dd" and try to retrieve a date with value "2014-06-11" it throws an error.

```
@Field(type = FieldType.Date, format = DateFormat.custom, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
private Date startDate;
```

Error:

```
java.time.DateTimeException: Unable to obtain Instant from TemporalAccessor: {},ISO resolved to 2014-06-11 of type java.time.format.Parsed
```

I tried with this also but get an error again:

```
@Field(type = FieldType.Date, format = DateFormat.date_optional_time)
private Date startDate;
```

I read in the documentation that I should use the pattern "uuuu-MM-dd" for elastic 7 version, but this doesn't work either.

Comment: It’s not my home field, so just a guess: try using `LocalDate` instead of `Date`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elasticsearch 7 uses the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html). Given below is an excerpt from https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html/#reference

> Properties that derive from TemporalAccessor must either have a @Field
> annotation of type FieldType.Date or a custom converter must be
> registered for this type. If you are using a custom date format, you
> need to use uuuu for the year instead of yyyy. This is due to a change
> in Elasticsearch 7.

Change you annotation and type as follows:

```
@Field(type = FieldType.Date, format = DateFormat.date)
private LocalDate startDate;
```

Learn more about the modern date-time API at **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

**Some more references:**

1. [Elasticsearch Built In Formats for date-time](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-date-format.html)
2. [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html)

Answer (score 1):

A `java.util.Date` is not a plain date consisting of a year,month and day, but an instant in time in the UTC timezone. There is no way to convert "2014-06-11" to an instant in time. What hours and minutes should be used? In what timezone?

Like Ole wrote in the comment, use `java.time.LocalDate` for this. This class is for exactly that use case: a year with a month and a day. And please stop using the old `java.util.Date` class. Since Java 8, there are the classes in the `java.time` package.

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been resolved By Spring Data Elasticsearch 4.0.5.
Spring Boot 2.3.5 use Spring Data Elasticsearch 4.0.5.
(Spring Boot 2.3.5 available Oct 29.2020.)

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/pull/538
DATAES-953 - DateTimeException on converting Instant or Date to custo…

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/releases/tag/4.0.5.RELEASE